# Going backwards Vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am using vue-router, how do I go backwards using the declarative way: `router-link` and `router.go(n)`? I know it's possible like this: `<h1 @click="$router.go(-1)"></h1>`, but `<router-link :to="$router.go(-1)" tag="h1"></router-link>` won't work because it requires string or object.

Comment: `@click="$router.go(-1)"` is the proper way to do it.

Comment: Have you seen my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this declaratively. See this issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/880